# systemd-networkd-wait-online.service keeps failing

Tags: systemd, ethernet, systemd-networkd

I am having a strange problem trying to get network working on Linux using systemd.

My network `eth0` is connected to a corporate network with a DHCP server:

```
# more /etc/systemd/network/main.network

#Main connection to the outside world
[Match]
Name=eth0
[Network]
DHCP=yes 
IPForward=yes
```

```
# networkctl status eth0

2: eth0
           Link File: n/a
        Network File: /etc/systemd/network/main.network
                Type: ether
               State: routable (configured)
          HW Address: 00:03:2d:32:85:3a (IBASE Technology, Inc.)
                 MTU: 1500
             Address: 10.0.7.134
                      fe80::203:2dff:fe32:853a
             Gateway: 10.0.7.1
                 DNS: 10.0.7.10
```

However, wait-online service fails:

```
# /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --interface eth0 --timeout=10

ignoring: sit0
Event loop failed: Connection timed out
```

The system had acquired a valid IP address on `eth0` so I don't understand why it would not be online.

I have another interface in the system, `eth1`, that is not plugged in.

Comment: Have you tried a higher timeout value?  In fact, the default is 120 seconds

Comment: I have the same problem. It is not due to timeout: after a few seconds eth0 is perfectly configured. Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that `systemd-networkd-wait-online` might be waiting for other interfaces to come up despite you specifying the `--interface` flag. The formatting for the flag that you gave originally shows `--interface eth0` although the manpage shows that the formatting for that flag should be either `-i eth0` or `--interface=eth0` so that could be the issue.

According to the manpage, another potential way to fix this issue would be to run the command with `--any`, which will wait for any interface to come online.

i.e.
`systemd-networkd-wait-online --any`

---

Answers to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381448/systemd-networkd-wait-online-failure), and info about configuring `systemd-networkd` that I found [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-networkd#systemd-networkd-wait-online) also show how you can edit the systemd service that performs this wait by running:

```
sudo systemctl edit systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

Then entering:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --any
```