# systemd-networkd-wait-online failure

Tags: linux, arch-linux, systemd, systemd-networkd

The default openvpn-server configuration file depends on systemd-networkd-wait-online, which times out with error:

```
systemd-networkd-wait-online[279]: Event loop failed: Connection timed out
```

My system has only 2 interfaces:

- lo, which is ignored
- eth0, is up and running and perfectly configured

Why does this times out? Is it a systemd bug?

Fabio

Comment: There is a bug report filed at: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6441. In brief, one cause which triggers this bug is disabling the ipv6 stack.

Comment: This may help to solve your problem: [A start job is running for wait for network to be configured](https://askubuntu.com/a/1160483/717636).

Answer (score 15):

Basically the same answer as @alexei, but the option `--any` allows you to wait for any interface to come online. You may also benefit from the `--timeout` option.

See the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.html#--any) for more information.

```
sudo systemctl edit systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

and add

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --any
```

The reason their is an extra blank `ExecStart=`, is to clear the existing service entry, the second one sets to a new value.

Answer (score 5):

It might be due to systemd-networkd-wait-online utility waiting for interfaces that are not going to come up (e.g. ethernet ports with unplugged cables) in some corner cases, like having two ethernet interfaces.

In my case, the workaround was to edit the service to pass `--ignore` arguments to the utility for the interfaces I don't want to wait for.

```
sudo systemctl edit systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

Add these lines:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --ignore=enp0s31f6
```

Answer (score 5):

Just adding to this that you can also specify a specific interface for `systemd-networkd-wait-online` to wait for using

```
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --interface=eth0
```

This will cause the service to ignore all other interfaces.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In case **you have configured network in `/etc/network/interfaces`**, NOT in `/etc/systemd/network`, then you can simply clean `/etc/systemd/network` folder:

```
rm /etc/systemd/network/*
```

In my case there was automatically created file `eth0.network`, which had instruction to configure `eth0` by DHCP. But since I configured static IP in `/etc/network/interfaces`, I simply removed `eth0.network` from `/etc/systemd/network`. Now system boots quickly.

Answer (score 0):

`systemd-networkd-wait-online` is looking up configurations of the interfaces of `systemd-networkd`. so in this case instead of modifying the service file itself one can set an [RequiredForOnline](https://systemd.network/systemd.network.html#RequiredForOnline=) or [ActivationPolicy](https://systemd.network/systemd.network.html#ActivationPolicy=) flag in the interfaces' [systemd.network](https://systemd.network/systemd.network.html) configuration file. E.g.

`/etc/systemd/network/enp0s31f6.network`:

```
[Match]
Name=enp0s31f6

[Link]
RequiredForOnline=no
```