# systemd-networkd-wait-online configuration: confusion about --any

Tags: systemd-networkd

```
 uname -a
 Linux meer 6.1.3-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed, 04 Jan 2023 16:28:15 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

But this is not a recent issue. It's been like this "for a while" - sorry.

I have three network devices and my network is taking over 8 seconds to come up.

```
 :> systemd-analyze blame
 8.590s systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

I have a `wait-online` override that adds the `--any` flag -- which I understand to mean that the wait-online will be satisfied after the first successful connection.

```
### Editing /etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.d/override.
conf
### Anything between here and the comment below will become the new contents of 
the file

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --any
```

I have three systemd.networkd files

```
> ls /etc/systemd/network/*.network
/etc/systemd/network/100-eno1.network - onboard ethernet
/etc/systemd/network/200-usb01.network - usb-ethernet
/etc/systemd/network/500-wlan0.network - wifi
```

My understanding is that systemd reads these files in lexical order -- 100,200,500 correct?

Then this snippet of journal shows that most of those  8 seconds are spent struggling with the wifi and the usb-ethernet before reading the 100 file and then **after** that onboard ethernet has come up, we are waiting for wifi,and then for usb-ethernet.

```
 journalctl -b -u systemd-networkd -u systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
 2023-01-07T07:01:11.167377-0800 meer systemd[1]: Starting Network Configuration...
 2023-01-07T07:01:11.259477-0800 meer systemd-networkd[310]: lo: Link UP
 2023-01-07T07:01:11.259482-0800 meer systemd-networkd[310]: lo: Gained carrier
 2023-01-07T07:01:11.259789-0800 meer systemd-networkd[310]: Enumeration completed
 2023-01-07T07:01:11.270757-0800 meer systemd[1]: Started Network Configuration.
 2023-01-07T07:01:11.286993-0800 meer systemd[1]: Starting Wait for Network to be Configured...
 2023-01-07T07:01:12.152228-0800 meer systemd-networkd-wait-online[351]: wlan0: Failed to update link state, ignoring: No such file or directory
 2023-01-07T07:01:12.365857-0800 meer systemd-networkd-wait-online[351]: eth0: Failed to update link state, ignoring: No such file or directory
 2023-01-07T07:01:12.454141-0800 meer systemd-networkd[310]: wlan0: found matching network '/etc/systemd/network/500-wlan0.network', based on potentially unpredictable inter>
 2023-01-07T07:01:12.454149-0800 meer systemd-networkd[310]: wlan0: Configuring with /etc/systemd/network/500-wlan0.network.
 2023-01-07T07:01:12.673305-0800 meer systemd-networkd[310]: eth0: Interface name change detected, renamed to eno1.
 2023-01-07T07:01:12.673353-0800 meer systemd-networkd[310]: wlan0: Link UP
 2023-01-07T07:01:12.674112-0800 meer systemd-networkd[310]: eno1: Configuring with /etc/systemd/network/100-eno1.network.
 2023-01-07T07:01:12.860420-0800 meer systemd-networkd[310]: eno1: Link UP
 2023-01-07T07:01:12.909088-0800 meer systemd-networkd[310]: wlan0: Link DOWN
 2023-01-07T07:01:12.970441-0800 meer systemd-networkd-wait-online[351]: wlan0: Failed to update link state, ignoring: No such file or directory
 2023-01-07T07:01:13.161606-0800 meer systemd-networkd[310]: wlan0: Link UP
 2023-01-07T07:01:13.172932-0800 meer systemd-networkd[310]: wlan0: Configuring with /etc/systemd/network/500-wlan0.network.
 2023-01-07T07:01:15.702912-0800 meer systemd-networkd[310]: eno1: Gained carrier
 2023-01-07T07:01:17.130156-0800 meer systemd-networkd[310]: eno1: Gained IPv6LL
 2023-01-07T07:01:17.815648-0800 meer systemd-networkd[310]: eno1: DHCPv6 address---
 2023-01-07T07:01:18.091443-0800 meer systemd-networkd[310]: wlan0: Connected WiFi access point: Hymanwallace (f8:f5:32:7d:d3:db)
 2023-01-07T07:01:18.212614-0800 meer systemd-networkd[310]: wlan0: Gained carrier
 2023-01-07T07:01:19.233866-0800 meer systemd-networkd[310]: wlan0: Gained IPv6LL
 2023-01-07T07:01:19.877409-0800 meer systemd[1]: Finished Wait for Network to be Configured.
 2023-01-07T07:01:20.001854-0800 meer systemd-networkd[310]: wlan0: DHCPv6 address ---
 2023-01-07T07:01:56.397053-0800 meer systemd-networkd[310]: eth0: Interface name change detected, renamed to usb01.
 2023-01-07T07:01:56.461015-0800 meer systemd-networkd[310]: usb01: Configuring with /etc/systemd/network/200-usb01.network.
 2023-01-07T07:01:56.468578-0800 meer systemd-networkd[310]: usb01: Link UP
 2023-01-07T07:01:59.058539-0800 meer systemd-networkd[310]: usb01: Gained carrier
 2023-01-07T07:02:00.886867-0800 meer systemd-networkd[310]: usb01: Gained IPv6LL
 2023-01-07T07:02:01.996701-0800 meer systemd-networkd[310]: usb01: DHCPv6 address -----
 ~
```

I want the 100 file read first and I want the system up after that `eno1` is up.

Where is the error in my understanding?
How can I correct the configuration?

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear, but I was having a similar issue (`networkd-wait-online` taking forever because ethernet cable is not connected) and adding the configuration override with the `--any` solved my issue. Now it starts quickly, even when `eth` is disconnected and `wlan` is connected

Comment: @GriffoGoes yes. It's buried in the post but I do have the --any flag in an override.

Comment: I wasn't clear on my comment, but your post actually provided me the solution (`any` param) that unfortunatelly didn't work for you. FYI, I'm using Ubuntu Server 22.04.2, and `uname -a` returns `Linux mini 5.15.0-69-generic #76-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 17 17:19:29 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to clear the `ExecStart` param before setting an override.
For example:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --any
```

Ref this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/742618)
Hope this helps.